# What are the most effective ways to stay anonymous in the internet?

Tags: tor, anonymity

I wonder how hackers can stay anonymous in the Internet. I have some ideas like using TOR or a chain of servers (for example a few SSH tunnels through different countries) but which of them are common? Are there more promising ways to stay anonymous?

Comment: Begueradj - please don't make one character edits. Especially ones like this one - your energy would have been better served identifying the duplicate and voting to close.

Answer (score 7):

Go to a cafeteria where free Wi-Fi is available. Take your laptop and run  [Tails Linux](https://tails.boum.org/) from a USB stick: your Internet connections will go through the Tor network which is the best implementation of [onion routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onion_routing), and offers very effective cryptographic tools to secure your online exchanges; and whatever you do  no traces will be saved in your USB stick -unless if you choose that explicitly by modifying the default settings.

Comment: You forgot something very important: --- **1.** Do not provide information which could be related to you. --- **2.** Consider that your Tor communication could be unusual in the café so if someone remembers you then your presence could be related to the time when the Tor session(s) were established from the café. ...but unless you provide other clues (the point 1. or camera recording of your hands, your screen etc...) it is normally not possible to relate the connections to the destination computers to you.

Comment: I think this is one of the dumbest things to do nowadays. You should be aware of the internet structure which u are using. You dont know if the cafeteria is led by police (happend many times this year) Also you forget about getting to the free Wi-Fi place. From your house to the cafetaria you are filmed so many times the police always have an photo of you. You should try to be anonymous from your own home, and that is something that isnt that hard anymore...

Answer (score 2):

I think [wardriving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wardriving) is very popular among hackers. 
You can find many open WiFi networks around the world, from where you can do things completely anonymous.

What you shouldn't do is transmit data which is related to your personal life over the network.

Answer (score 1):

A [vpn](/questions/tagged/vpn) is nowadays a very common way to stay more hidden on the internet. VPN's aren't that expensive anymore. You should take a look into this article, they really gave pro's and cons on several VPN services: https://torrentfreak.com/anonymous-vpn-service-provider-review-2015-150228/

But to stay hidden you have to really really change your webbrowsing behaviour also. You should not make any link to old data. With that I mean that you should not browse to Facebook using that VPN. If you always use the same VPN they can easily track you because you use that same VPN IP address on many other social media. Its really a doom scenario, but in my opinion, it is extremely hard to be anonymous.

My advise to be 100% secure; buy a new laptop and start clean on that device. Never login to old accounts on websites/emails whatever can link you to your old identity.

Answer (score 1):

1. Tor
   Enough said! Install this.
2. An e-mail address that does not link back to you
   E-mail providers like Gmail, Yahoo now require a lot of details which will tie that e-mail account to you. For example, Gmail now requires your mobile phone number. Open Tor, go to [Yandex Mail](https://mail.yandex.ru/). This is one of the e-mail service providers who offer an account without creating a fuss. The website is even accessible over Tor.
3. Create a PGP key for the above e-mail address.
   Pretty Good Privacy!!!

Comment: I think one should be careful with simply stating that `tor` is the solution to everything. Many websites state that the NSA will try to dig deeper into data distributed through `tor` than through the "normal network". Furthermore some people simply use `tor` the wrong way.

Comment: What do you mean with the "wrong way" for example?